# is it possible ui pickerview like Iphone in android

Tags: android

i am using default android spinner for drop down selection from multiple items array ,but i see the ui in Iphone it looks cool then android then is it possible to make like iphone ui picker view in android means a dropdown would be open with bottom to top animation with a "done" button on upper side of picker view and when i choose one and press "done" then that item should be selected as in iphone...
i think android must have this feature bcoz android is more better then Iphone as in cost and newer version of android capture the whole market ,
so pls any one help me..
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check the following: http://android-devblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/wheel-ui-contol-backgrounds.html

> Introduction to the Wheel control
>   The Wheel control layouts
>   Scrolling the wheel control
>   Ideas for the future

Do not forget to check "See Also"

Answer (score 0):

Usually they use [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html) in Android

If you want a wheel thingy like in iPhone [use this](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/)

Comment: where is souce code,actually i see a application in android which uses this widget but i was searchin in gogle but not found similar to that,so in your given link whee is source code....

Comment: Click on `Source > Browse > trunk `